# using eas build: Version code 1 has already been used. Try another version code

Tags: react-native, visual-studio, expo, eas

I'm using eas build to upload to google play but I get the messeage:

Version code 1 has already been used. Try another version code

I'm currently on 248 4.

I want to update this to 249 5.

How can I do that. I'm using Visual studio code and expo.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `App.json` look for android,buildNumber and increment it from 1 to 2.